# Un-Identified Components in Java SE

Tags: java

Is there anyone here who knows what kind of components is this in Java SE? Alternatively, is there something you can suggest to me just to have this kind of component?

Picture: http://s10.postimage.org/3msnaw0s7/image.jpg

Comment: This is not a standard Java component. You need to build one which suits you needs using a number of components.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir Peter, I think I will try the SwingX component just like Elite Gentleman said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is combining [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) like in [this example](http://eppleton.de/blog/?p=970). The item on the right of your image, will require a combination of components to get the result.

Comment: Hey sir, thank you so much, I'll really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's called task pane. You can look for a tutorial to build one, like 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TaskPanewindowhomestyle.htm, dig a component library like swingx or buy a commercial component from a company like jidesoft.com